# Datasource connection failure in WebSphere Application Server 7: Error Code = 17,433

Tags: websphere, datasource, ws-security, websphere-7

I am trying to configure data-source in WAS 7 and facing below mentioned error.

Error:

```
Messages
The test connection operation failed for data source APDataSource on server adminagent at node appsrv01 with the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in callDSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = 17,433. View JVM logs for further details.
```

JVM Log:

```
Error Message: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean com.ibm.ws.console.probdetermination.form.StreamRedirectDetailForm in any scope
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: null
Error Stack:
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean com.ibm.ws.console.probdetermination.form.StreamRedirectDetailForm in any scope
     at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.lookup(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.DefineTag.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
     at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._detailTitleLayout._jspService(_detailTitleLayout.java:365)
     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:239)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:527)
     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
     at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._configboxLayout._jspService(_configboxLayout.java:343)
     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
     at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:239)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:341)
     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
     at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:217)
     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:927)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:494)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:315)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:288)
     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1016)
     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:639)
     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

Steps I followed:

1. Configured alias in Global Security

Global security > JAAS - J2C authentication data > appsrv01/APDataSource

1. In Datasource > Security settings

   picked appsrv01/APDataSource from drop down box
2. Test Connection

   Error Code: 17,433

Ref Followed : [IBM DEVELOPER WORKS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tdat_tccrtprovds.html)

Comment: May you check discussion at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=84256&start=0&tstart=0 . It seems to be a similar problem, with same error code while trying to get a connection from datasource. For summary, it's generally stated that recycling node agents helps (assuming you are using a federated environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the database that is used?

What does the error code - **17,433** represent for that database vendor?

*The stack does not show any SQL involved*, yet the error message is a **SQLException**? Is there something that is not displayed here present in your logs?

Have a look at both ***SysOut*** and ***SysErr*** to see where the SQLException stack is placed and paste them here for people to have a look and help out.

HTH